# Custom controls textbox Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

For my canvas element I use the library Fabric.js.
I try to add custom functions and icons and I need a little help with this.
On the official website from Fabric you can see dev documentation.
I have read the documentation and programming this in a pen (see snipped)

```js
    var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
    // create a rect object
  var deleteIcon = "data:image/svg+xml,%3C%3Fxml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'%3F%3E%3C!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd'%3E%3Csvg version='1.1' id='Ebene_1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' x='0px' y='0px' width='595.275px' height='595.275px' viewBox='200 215 230 470' xml:space='preserve'%3E%3Ccircle style='fill:%23F44336;' cx='299.76' cy='439.067' r='218.516'/%3E%3Cg%3E%3Crect x='267.162' y='307.978' transform='matrix(0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 0.7071 -222.6202 340.6915)' style='fill:white;' width='65.545' height='262.18'/%3E%3Crect x='266.988' y='308.153' transform='matrix(0.7071 0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 398.3889 -83.3116)' style='fill:white;' width='65.544' height='262.179'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E";

  var cloneIcon = "data:image/svg+xml,%3C%3Fxml version='1.0' encoding='iso-8859-1'%3F%3E%3Csvg version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' viewBox='0 0 55.699 55.699' width='100px' height='100px' xml:space='preserve'%3E%3Cpath style='fill:%23010002;' d='M51.51,18.001c-0.006-0.085-0.022-0.167-0.05-0.248c-0.012-0.034-0.02-0.067-0.035-0.1 c-0.049-0.106-0.109-0.206-0.194-0.291v-0.001l0,0c0,0-0.001-0.001-0.001-0.002L34.161,0.293c-0.086-0.087-0.188-0.148-0.295-0.197 c-0.027-0.013-0.057-0.02-0.086-0.03c-0.086-0.029-0.174-0.048-0.265-0.053C33.494,0.011,33.475,0,33.453,0H22.177 c-3.678,0-6.669,2.992-6.669,6.67v1.674h-4.663c-3.678,0-6.67,2.992-6.67,6.67V49.03c0,3.678,2.992,6.669,6.67,6.669h22.677 c3.677,0,6.669-2.991,6.669-6.669v-1.675h4.664c3.678,0,6.669-2.991,6.669-6.669V18.069C51.524,18.045,51.512,18.025,51.51,18.001z M34.454,3.414l13.655,13.655h-8.985c-2.575,0-4.67-2.095-4.67-4.67V3.414z M38.191,49.029c0,2.574-2.095,4.669-4.669,4.669H10.845 c-2.575,0-4.67-2.095-4.67-4.669V15.014c0-2.575,2.095-4.67,4.67-4.67h5.663h4.614v10.399c0,3.678,2.991,6.669,6.668,6.669h10.4 v18.942L38.191,49.029L38.191,49.029z M36.777,25.412h-8.986c-2.574,0-4.668-2.094-4.668-4.669v-8.985L36.777,25.412z M44.855,45.355h-4.664V26.412c0-0.023-0.012-0.044-0.014-0.067c-0.006-0.085-0.021-0.167-0.049-0.249 c-0.012-0.033-0.021-0.066-0.036-0.1c-0.048-0.105-0.109-0.205-0.194-0.29l0,0l0,0c0-0.001-0.001-0.002-0.001-0.002L22.829,8.637 c-0.087-0.086-0.188-0.147-0.295-0.196c-0.029-0.013-0.058-0.021-0.088-0.031c-0.086-0.03-0.172-0.048-0.263-0.053 c-0.021-0.002-0.04-0.013-0.062-0.013h-4.614V6.67c0-2.575,2.095-4.67,4.669-4.67h10.277v10.4c0,3.678,2.992,6.67,6.67,6.67h10.399 v21.616C49.524,43.26,47.429,45.355,44.855,45.355z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E%0A"

  var deleteImg = document.createElement('img');
  deleteImg.src = deleteIcon;

  var cloneImg = document.createElement('img');
  cloneImg.src = cloneIcon;

  fabric.Object.prototype.transparentCorners = false;
  fabric.Object.prototype.cornerColor = 'blue';
  fabric.Object.prototype.cornerStyle = 'circle';


    var rect = new fabric.Rect({
      left: 100,
      top: 50,
      fill: 'yellow',
      width: 200,
      height: 100,
      objectCaching: false,
      stroke: 'lightgreen',
      strokeWidth: 4,
    });

    canvas.add(rect);
    canvas.setActiveObject(rect);
  

  function renderIcon(icon) {
    return function renderIcon(ctx, left, top, styleOverride, fabricObject) {
      var size = this.cornerSize;
      ctx.save();
      ctx.translate(left, top);
      ctx.rotate(fabric.util.degreesToRadians(fabricObject.angle));
      ctx.drawImage(icon, -size/2, -size/2, size, size);
      ctx.restore();
    }
  }

  fabric.Object.prototype.controls.deleteControl = new fabric.Control({
    x: 0.5,
    y: -0.5,
    offsetY: -16,
    offsetX: 16,
    cursorStyle: 'pointer',
    mouseUpHandler: deleteObject,
    render: renderIcon(deleteImg),
    cornerSize: 24
  });

  fabric.Object.prototype.controls.clone = new fabric.Control({
    x: -0.5,
    y: -0.5,
    offsetY: -16,
    offsetX: -16,
    cursorStyle: 'pointer',
    mouseUpHandler: cloneObject,
    render: renderIcon(cloneImg),
    cornerSize: 24
  });

 

  function deleteObject(eventData, transform) {
                var target = transform.target;
        var canvas = target.canvas;
            canvas.remove(target);
        canvas.requestRenderAll();
    }

  function cloneObject(eventData, transform) {
    var target = transform.target;
    var canvas = target.canvas;
    target.clone(function(cloned) {
      cloned.left += 10;
      cloned.top += 10;
      canvas.add(cloned);
    });
  }
        var text = new fabric.Textbox('Add Icons', {
            cursorColor :"blue",
            top:200,
            left:150,
            lockMovementY: false,
            height: 200,
        });
        canvas.add(text);
        canvas.setActiveObject(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/fabric@latest/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="400" height="300" style="border:1px solid #ccc"></canvas>
```

But the code does only work by shapes and not by textboxes
I have searched for a solution but can not find this.
Who can help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

**Textbox** prototype has `controls` property of iteself. You also need to add new `deleteControl` property to `Textbox.prototype.controls` and it reads as follows

```js
fabric.Textbox.prototype.controls.deleteControl = new fabric.Control({
   // ...
})
```